# Two potential ways of presenting results, is there a preference?

Tags: publications, physics

In a short paper I am writing, I have developed a fairly complex model. To express it in a highly watered down fashion, the purpose of the paper is to study the variation of a Variable Y with an independent Variable M.

My current way of presenting the results section is as follows:

1. Show the most important result upfront: plot M vs Y. However its difficult to understand the variation just from this plot, because of the complex nature of the underlying physics. Hence..
2. Describe the fundamental physics in the domain as a function of time and space c(x,t,M). Plot c(x,t,M) as a function of x and t. Describe why c(x,t,M) makes sense from a fundamental physics perspective. x=space, t=time.
3. Plot C1(t,M). C1(t,M)=F(c(x,t,M)), and explain why C1(t,M) makes sense
4. Y(M)=F1(C1(t,M)). So Tie #1 and #3 together, and describe why it makes sense and its implications.

The reason why I chose the above logic structure is because I thought I should present the most important result (plot M vs Y) first. I also learnt about this method of presenting results in a management consulting competitions, and I thought it makes sense at that time.

However, I am starting to feel that maybe this is making it more complicated and is not the way academic journals work. I tried looking at some results, but I am not able to directly relate their work to mine.

I am thinking of an alternate structure

1. Describe the fundamental physics in the domain as a function of time and space c(x,t,M). Plot c(x,t,M) as a function of x and t. Describe why c(x,t,M) makes sense from a fundamental physics perspective.
2. Plot C1(t,M)=F(c(x,t,M)), and explain why C1(t,M) makes sense
3. plot M vs Y. Explain why it makes sense and the implications of the trend.

Do you think that the second logic structure is better?

Hope this make sense, or I can explain more..

Comment: I would prefer second way of demonstration.

Answer (score 2):

I'm inclined for the second, but having a clear explanation of your goal in the abstract, so the reader knows what you are getting at.

Your want your readers to know you are taking the path to Oz, but not necessarily how the sightseeing are until you get there.